# Scope Chaining in Mongoid 2.2 with Rails 3.0.9 and Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, scoping

Hi I have application running on Ruby 1.8.7 (*i am presently not in a position to update this to 1.9.2*) and Rails 3.0.9 running mongoid 2.2.2.

I have a couple of named scopes which I have defined as follows

```
scope :for_pickups, where(:state => "accepted")
scope :confirmed_shipments, where(:state => "confirmed", :created_at.lt => Date.today - 1.day).desc(:created_at).limit(10)
scope :undelivered_shipments, Proc.new{ |start_date_utc, end_date_utc|
                                  start_date_utc = (Date.today - 7.days).to_time.utc if !start_date_utc.present?
                                  end_date_utc = Date.today.to_time.utc if !end_date_utc.present?
                                  any_of({:created_at.gte => start_date_utc, :created_at.lte => end_date_utc}, 
                                         {:pickup_date.gte => start_date_utc, :pickup_date.lte => end_date_utc}, 
                                         {:desired_arrival_date.gte => start_date_utc, :desired_arrival_date.lte => end_date_utc}).
                                  where(:state.in => ["accepted"], :state.nin => ["delivered"]).without(:carrier_digest, :carrier_label_image_base64, :carrier_label_html_base64)
                                }

scope :search, Proc.new{|search_params| 
                    regexp = Regexp.new(/.*#{search_params.strip}.*/i, true)
                    where(:golfer_name => regexp)
                  }
```

This seems to work well and return the expected values when I use them on their own but when I use scope chaining it gets messed up.

For instance when I run `Model.undelivered_shipments.search("sid")` i get an array which has :ids as the first parameter

```
[:ids, #[{:created_at=>{"$gte"=>Thu Sep 27 18:30:00 UTC 2012, "$lte"=>Thu Oct 04 18:30:00 UTC 2012}}, {:pickup_date=>{"$gte"=>Thu Sep 27 18:30:00 UTC 2012, "$lte"=>Thu Oct 04 18:30:00 UTC 2012}}, {:desired_arrival_date=>{"$gte"=>Thu Sep 27 18:30:00 UTC 2012, "$lte"=>Thu Oct 04 18:30:00 UTC 2012}}], :_id=>"sid", :state=>{"$nin"=>["delivered"], "$in"=>["accepted"]}},
  options:  {:fields=>{:carrier_digest=>0, :carrier_label_html_base64=>0, :carrier_label_image_base64=>0}},
  class:    Shipment,
  embedded: false>
]
```

Not sure why it returns this and why mongoid criteria defines `:_id => 'sid'` However when i run the `search` before the `undelivered_shipments` method it generates the criteria correctly.

It works if run it with other scopes like `for_pickups.search` etc but not with the undelivered shipments. I understand I am missing something but I've been through the docs and I can't find anything that really helps. I would really appreciate any help on this

Thanks in advance.